# scala.collections.javaconverters._ Error : value map is not a member of java.util.Set

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have been using `scala.collections.JavaConversions` for implicitly converting, but decided to upgrade the scala version and use `scala.collections.JavaConverters` instead, I'm confused with the explicit conversion with `JavaConverters`. Can anyone tell me how to convert the below code to use javaconveters.

```
availableColors.entrySet()
      // Parse the hexadecimal string to the RGB vector
      .map(entry => (entry.getKey, parseHexColor(entry.getValue.getBackground)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `asScala` method to convert it to Scala's mutable set.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

availableColors.entrySet().asScala
      .map(entry => (entry.getKey, parseHexColor(entry.getValue.getBackground)))
```